# How to make "incremental" replace in files with bash

Tags: bash, search, replace, text

I need to search files in directory with specific pattern (for example `foobar`) and replace them with `foobarXXX`, where `XXX` is a number. For example, there were two original file

snt130.txt

> My mistress' eyes are nothing like **foobar**;
>   **foobar** is far more red than her lips' red;

snt18.txt

> Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?
>  
>   Thou art more lovely and more **foobar**:

After proccessing I need something like this (order of numbers does not matter, just uniqueness)

snt130.txt

> My mistress' eyes are nothing like **foobar001**;
>   **foobar002** is far more red than her lips' red;

snt18.txt

> Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?
>  
>   Thou art more lovely and more **foobar003**:

What is the simplest way to perform this search&replace task (preferably with `bash`)

Comment: How do we determine the order of files? That `snt130` should be done first and `snt18` next? Can it be in any order

Comment: "order of numbers does not matter, just uniqueness"

Comment: Bash isn’t much of a text editor...

Comment: I would suggest an accurate python solution

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - Python solution is interesting too

Comment: @Loom, also, you could tell me how many occurrences should be processed with `grep -wo 'foobar' *.txt | wc -l`. Then, if the number would be quite "big" - I would apply parallel processing which will give us not only accurate but **fast** solution

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat f1
My mistress' eyes are nothing like foobar;
foobar is far more red than her lips' red;
$ cat f2
Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?
Thou art more lovely and more foobar:
```

With `perl`

```
$ perl -i -pe 's/foobar\K/sprintf "%03d", ++$i/ge' f1 f2
$ cat f1
My mistress' eyes are nothing like foobar001;
foobar002 is far more red than her lips' red;
$ cat f2
Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?
Thou art more lovely and more foobar003:
```

- default value of uninitialized variable is `0` in numeric context
- `e` modifier allows to use Perl code in replacement section
- `foobar\K` string to replace, `\K` used just as a convenience here

With `gawk` having inplace extension and assuming only one instance of string per line

```
gawk -i inplace -v s='foobar' '$0 ~ s{sub(s, sprintf("%s%03d", s, ++i))} 1' f1 f2
```